# What is $VERSION-SANDBOX when adding midtrans to dependencies

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am learning midtrans (payment gateway). I get [this documentation](https://mobile-docs.midtrans.com/#installation). There is writen `compile 'com.midtrans:uikit:$VERSION-SANDBOX'`. What should i write in $VERSION-SANDBOX? I've search on google and ask people but no result. I try to write `compile 'com.midtrans:uikit:100'` but not work :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the latest Version of midtrans [here](https://github.com/veritrans/veritrans-android/releases). So it will be `compile 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.5.1'`